# Error when upgrading Room to 2.4.3 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'XMethodElement.hasAnyOf'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I recently upgraded my Android project's Room version from 2.3.0-alpha02 to 2.4.3 and now I'm getting this error when I compile. I don't have any code to share because nowhere in my code is there a reference for `hasAnyOf` or `XMethodElement`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean androidx.room.compiler.processing.XMethodElement.hasAnyOf(kotlin.reflect.KClass[])'
```

The only reference I can find for `hasAnyOf` is in a comment here
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160322705 where it says:

> Rename hasAnyOf() to hasAnyAnnotation()

settings.gradle.kts

[image]

[image]

build.gradle.kts

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've upgraded Room, but not the Room Compiler (what you'd use with `kapt` or `ksp`). Can you include the `dependencies` block where you add your Room dependencies?

Comment: do you have annotationProcessor specified? in my case it's like this: `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"` That's the only additional entry I have after migrating from 2.3.0. I remember I also checked all the dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.room/room-runtime/2.4.3)

Comment: that's what my kapt() line is doing, right?